# ChartJS with ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a chart with (chartjs.org). I have a database and in my php document I retrieved the data into a json file:

```
print json_encode($result->fetch_all());
```

and the result is this, which is fine:

```
[["1.1","59.7701"],["1.2","66.6667"],["1.3","65.5172"],["1.4","65.5172"],  ["1.5","56.3218"],["1.6","58.6207"],["1.7","58.1395"],["1.8","58.6207"],["1.9","61.6279"],["2.1","65.1163"],["2.2","70.1149"],["2.3","57.4713"],["2.4","54.0230"],["2.5","60.9195"],["3.1","52.3256"],["3.2","60.4651"],["3.3","69.7674"],["3.4","52.3256"],["4.1","52.3256"]]
```

The problem is when I am trying to get these:

```
    $(function () {
  $('#go').click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: '../output.php', data: {MOD_CODE: $('#MOD_CODE').val()}, dataType: 'json',
      success: function(d){
        console.log(d);
        var data = { labels:[], datasets:[{label:$('#MOD_CODE').val() + ' results', data:[], }]};
        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
          data.labels.push(d[i][0]);
          data.datasets[0].data.push(parseFloat(d[i][1]));
        }
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'radar',
          data: data,
          options:{
            responsive:false,
            scale:{ticks: {beginAtZero: true}}}});//.for
      }//.success
    }); //.ajax
  })//.click
});//.function
```

This is the folder structure, maybe I putting the path wrong.

```
/folder
-js/chart.js
-doc.php
```

It is strange that is not passing through the "success" of the ajax. I cannot see the `console.log(d);`

Comment: there also is an error hook which gets passed some error messsages/object. Try to implement that an see if you can find the error.

Comment: I have used: error: function (request, status, error) { alert(error.responseText);} In request, its giving me the HTML, with status, "undefined", and same for error... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the php file generate with this code:

```
print json_encode($result->fetch_all());
```

It was not plain PHP, it contained HTML and content in general.

In order to generate a json doc it must be plain PHP, and the call in jquery then can collect the data.

For that reason when I check the error request, it was giving me the whole HTML page.